# Require assistance in unit testing zoom integration in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Using [flutter_zoom_sdk](https://github.com/craigspicer/flutter_zoom_sdk) , the [joinMeeting()](https://github.com/craigspicer/flutter_zoom_sdk#join-meeting) method is used in the flutter application to join a zoom meeting upon clicking a meeting card.

Unit tests need to be written on the same. How to go about writing unit tests for the following:

1. User successfully joined meeting.
2. User exited from meeting.

This is what we wrote as of now :

```
class zoomMeeting {
  bool hasMeetingStarted = false;
  bool hasMeetingEnded = false;
  bool hasMeetingServerConnected = false;
  String currentStatus = "";

  zoomMeeting(hasMeetingStarted, hasMeetingEnded);
  void checkMeetingStarted() {}

  void joinMeeting(String meetingID, String meetingPassword) {
    // print("ssd");
    ZoomOptions zoomOptions = ZoomOptions(
      domain: "zoom.us",
      appKey: API_KEY, //API KEY FROM ZOOM - Sdk API Key
      appSecret: API_SECRET, //API SECRET FROM ZOOM - Sdk API Secret
    );
    ZoomMeetingOptions meetingOptions = ZoomMeetingOptions(
        userEmail: "",
        userId: "Guest",
        meetingId: meetingID,
        meetingPassword: meetingPassword,
        disableMinimizeMeeting: "true",
        disableDialIn: "true",
        disableDrive: "true",
        disableInvite: "true",
        disableShare: "false",
        disableTitlebar: "false",
        viewOptions: "false",
        noAudio: "false",
        noDisconnectAudio: "true");

    ZoomView zoom = ZoomView();
    zoom.initZoom(zoomOptions).then((results) {
      if (results[0] == 0) {
        zoom.onMeetingStatus().listen((status) {
          // String currentStatus = status[0];
          // print("Status: " + currentStatus, name: 'Meeting.dart');
          switch (currentStatus) {
            case MEETING_STATUS_CONNECTING:
              // print("Its connecting");

              currentStatus = "MEETING STATUS CONNECTING";
              break;
            case MEETING_STATUS_DISCONNECTING:

              // print("Its disconnecting");
              currentStatus = "MEETING IS DISCONNECTING";
              print(currentStatus);
              break;
            case MEETING_STATUS_IN_MEETING:
              currentStatus = "USER IS IN MEETING";
              break;
            case MEETING_STATUS_FAILED:
              currentStatus = "MEETING HAS FAILED";
              break;
          }
        });
        zoom.joinMeeting(meetingOptions);
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      // print("Error: " + error, name: 'Meeting.dart');
      print(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The idea is to get the value of current status to match with the meeting status messages provided in github. However the expected value never matches actual value (currentStatus is always a empty string).